# type safety issue for List<Object[]>

Tags: java, generics

I'm using native sql to retrieve data from db. I'm getting list of Object[].

```
List<Object[]> objectList = session.createSQLQuery(query).setParameter("customerId", customerId).list();
```

I'm getting below warning

> Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to
>   conform to List

How to fix this ?

Comment: There's nothing to fix, you can get rid of the warning with a `@SuppressWarnings`.

Comment: Suppressing warnings is not always a good thing. It's like turning off the check engine light on your car. There is obviously an issue, it should be addressed. You can adjust what warnings are displayed in the settings of Eclipse (if that's what you're using). But you should not get in the habit if just "suppressing warnings".

Comment: I turn off 'unchecked conversion' and 'raw type operation' warnings. If you have legacy libraries in your project, it's more important to be able to see **3 significant warnings** than 1000 non-issues. Frankly I don't believe generic type warnings **have ever saved me a single bug** in 6 years, 8 major projects and 4+ megabytes of source code. Strangely enough I don't get _confused_ as to whether I actually have Customers in my `customerList`.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because the API you are using doesn't support generics. Consider upgrading to the latest version or using a @SuppressWarnings.

You should of course use @SuppressWarnings only if you are absolutely certain if the query return the proper type.

Also you should always document the reason for suppressing the warning as well, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

When using an api doesn't support generics returns a paramterized type the type argument must be treated being a wildcard.

```
List<?> objectList = session.createSQLQuery(query).setParameter("customerId", customerId).list();
```

The above will compile without a warning. Obviously this isn't the type you want though. So you have to test the cast item by item as, technically, a `List<?>` could contain anything.

```
for(Object object : objectList){
    if(object instanceof Object[]){
       //Do stuff.
    }
}
```

Now in practice if you know ahead of time what the return type should be you can just suppress the warning and carry on. Just know that if you are wrong, you'll get the cast exception thrown at the code that accesses the list rather than at the code that performed the incorrect "cast" on the list as a whole.

Comment: You should only "check type & survive", if you're intending to write fault-tolerant code & that is the correct location to place the fault-tolerance at. I also strongly prefer the abnormal as a "guard condition" style -- if _not the right type_ then break/return/continue out of normal flow. This is much clearer than a "normal control flow" deeply nested in conditionals.